# Detecting FR/FF button event in MPMoviePlayerController UI?

Tags: button, mpmovieplayercontroller

Basically long pressing of FR(fast rewind)/FF(fast forward) causes directional scrubbing. But iPod, YouTube app detects short tapping of these buttons and uses it for navigating to previous/next tracks.

How can I archive this feature? Is this possible? Or should I go view-hierarchy hack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this with view hierarchy hack. This is not recommended and should be avoided as much as possible. But I note here for further reference. To mark **there is no accessible way currently**. This hack is applied to only specific version (4.3) of iOS SDK.

1. Iterate all view hierarchy of `-[MPMoviePlayerController view]`.
2. Find subclass of `UIButton`. And add target-action handler to all of them. (you can check for subclass of `MPTransportButton`)
3. In handler, you can filter by tags. Only navigation buttons are tagged. Each tag means `1` = play/pause, `2` = previous, `4` = next button.

Take care about this is just an hack. Will not be guaranteed to work or pass on AppStore.

If you have experience of rejection by this method, please comment me. It'll be very appreciated.